# How to check for date in C# textbox and display whether the date is before or later than DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, datetime, textbox, windows-forms-designer, datetime-format

I have a windows form program that reads from txt files and displays them in a textbox, the output can be`"Test w/c 07/03/16 AT 21/04/2016" or "AT 09/05/2016" or "w/c 07/03/2016  AT  17/03/2016 w/c 25/04/2016". I am loading 7 text files into it, some contain either 1, 2 or 3 dates.

How would I detect these dates and be able to output whether the dates detected are before or after `DateTime.Now`?

Comment: Convert your strings into a `DateTime` and compare them against `DateTime.Now`

Answer (score 1):

If your string is *always* in `"Test w/c dd/MM/yy AT dd/MM/yyyy"` format, you can [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split) your string with white space, take the *relevant* strings, parse them to `DateTime` with [`ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact) and compare them with `DateTime.Now` value.

```
var s = "Test w/c 07/03/16 AT 21/04/2016";
var arr = s.Split(' ');
var firstDate = DateTime.ParseExact(arr[2], "dd/MM/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var secondDate = DateTime.ParseExact(arr[4], "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

and you can compare them like;

```
if(firstDate < DateTime.Now)
// before
if(firstDate > DateTime.Now)
//after
if(secondDate < DateTime.Now)
// before
if(secondDate > DateTime.Now)
//after
if(firstDate < DateTime.Now && secondDate < DateTime.Now)
//Both before
if(firstDate > DateTime.Now && secondDate > DateTime.Now)
//Both after
etc..
```